# How to take the average of n random forest iterations?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

Is there a parameter in sklearn that can be tweaked to run a random forest (or other estimator) multiple times to smooth out variation between runs? What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just simply smooth out the variations between the runs manually. What you can do is  perform hyper parameter tuning using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) ( or you can look at other similar methods as well [at this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html). Also you can also look at doing [Cross-validation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~schneide/tut5/node42.html) of your dataset for better performance of your estimator. You can have a look at the methods in [Sklearn for cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

Also please provide more information for your problem, like the type of problem you are solving, dataset, etc. so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

`VotingClassifier` with soft voting may be what you are looking for. In general, given two sets of predictions, you may take the geometric mean of the prediction to smooth it out.

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean
df = pd.DataFrame()
#prediction renamed in 1.csv,2.csv... for convenience

for i in range(1,4):
    data = pd.read_csv('{}.csv'.format(i),index_col='id')
    data = data.rename(columns={'proba':i})
    df = pd.concat([df,data],axis=1)

df['proba'] = gmean(df.iloc[:,1:4],axis=1)
output = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':df.index,'proba':df.proba})
output.to_csv('submissions.csv',index=False)
```